# Getting Mailgun error when sending email with attachment as part of async series

Tags: node.js, mailgun, async.js

I have a NodeJs application that runs a variation of tasks but one of them is to produce a report and email it to my client. I am using Mailgun to send the email and have no issues with it sending email elswhere in my code.

As the report needs to be generated into a CSV file which could be lengthy and then attached to the email I have written them into an async series.

The problem is when I put everything together, I get an error message from Mailgun

```
{ message: '\'from\' parameter is missing' }
```

My code is very simple as below

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        User.find({}, function(err, foundUsers){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                User.csvReadStream(foundUsers)
                    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('dailyReport.csv'));
                callback(null, 'Created Report');
            }
        });
    },
    function(callback) {
        sendReport();
        callback(null, 'Sent Email');
    }
],
function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

With the function here

```
function sendReport () {
var filepath = path.join(__dirname, '../', 'dailyReport.csv');
var data = {
    from: "mailgun@myemail.co.uk",
    to: 'me@myemail.co.uk',
    subject: 'Daily Report',
    text: 'Daily CSV report from ...',
    attachment: filepath
};
console.log(data);
mg.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
console.log("Report Sent");
return;
}
```

I have sent a support message to Mailgun but they have been unable to help so far.

The strange thing is, if I call the function outside of the series, the email is sent. If I call the function inside the series but without the attachment element, it also sends the email!

I am wondering if it's something fundamental with the way the series (I have also tried this with async waterfall) handles the variables.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out sending attachments with mailgun-js?

Comment: @mepley, I was unable to get it working how I wanted so I went for the approach of sending email through Amazon SES. Instead of sending the attachment I first uploaded the file to Amazon S3 and then attached a link to the file within the email. This works great.